# NBFC - Notebook Fan Control

Tags: kubuntu, hp, fan, overheating, fancontrol

I want to make fan run at full speed. NBFS is working in my laptop, and I can change speed. The only thing I need is the settings to make it run always on full speed. HP ProBook 6550b.xml file is working in my HP EliteBook 8440p.

The main issue is that, as soon as the fan speed reaches the target speed (100% in this case), the figures stuck there, but the fan speed become very low. I believe it is around 20%.

I've tried with different percentages like 50,60,90% etc., but every time as soon it reaches that target speed, the fan speed drops back to around 20%.  When this happens, the `mono /opt/nbfc/nbfc.exe status -a` command shows that current speed is same as target speed while actually it is lower then that (near 20%).

How can I fix it so that my fan keeps running at target speed (full speed - 100%).

Also see the [issue](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/issues/1217) I have created on the NBFC repo.

Comment: NBFC is a 3rd party tool that is not distributed with Ubuntu, you would get better results asking directly on their github page.